How to compose a larger circuit onto a smaller circuit in Qiskit, adding extra quantum registers to some fixed list
$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|{#1}\rangle}$
I have a Qiskit quantum circuit for multiplication $M$, that I want to compose onto another qiskit quantum circuit for inner product of vectors $I$. $M$ uses some ancillary qubits to perform the map $\ket{a}\ket{b}\ket{c} \mapsto \ket{a}\ket{b}\ket{c\oplus (a\cdot b)}$. Ideally when I compose $M$ onto $I$ as a subroutine, I would only want to declare and map the quantum states (registers) of $I$ that I care about: $\ket{a},\ket{b},\ket{c}$ and let the additional qubits be counted as some ancillas in $I$, maybe in some fixed register anc, whose length can be appropriately extended.
According to the Qiskit documentation, to compose, $M$ can be narrower or of equal width to $I$, and methods like extend have been deprecated and removed. How can I go about doing this, if at all?
I would be okay using any other SDK like Cirq, as I need a QASM2 dump at the end. But my circuits use classically controlled operations, which Cirq does not seem to support.

If you already know how many ancillas are needed for each subcircuit, just add to your circuit ancillas enough to support the subcircuit with maximum number of ancillas, then pass a subset of these qubits according to the need. For example:
qr = QuantumRegister(4)
anc = AncillaRegister(10)
circ = QuantumCircuit(qr, anc)

# subcircuit1 needs 5 ancillas:
circ.compose(subcircuit1, qr[:] + anc[0:5], inplace=True)

# subcircuit2 needs 7 ancillas:
circ.compose(subcircuit2, qr[:] + anc[0:7], inplace=True)


Another solution is to dynamically add ancilla qubits to your circuit when needed:
Assuming that

Subcircuits use zeroed ancilla bits.
Subcircuits represent ancilla qubits using instances of AncillaQubit class (directly or indirectly through AncillaRegister)

then you can monkey-patch QuantumCircuit such that whenever you compose any subcircuit to your circuit the needed ancilla qubits will be added automatically as follows:
from typing import Optional, Sequence, Union
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit, AncillaQubit
from qiskit.circuit.instruction import Instruction
from qiskit.circuit.quantumcircuit import QubitSpecifier, ClbitSpecifier

def compose_with_auto_ancillas(
        self,
        other: Union["QuantumCircuit", Instruction],
        qubits: QubitSpecifier | Sequence[QubitSpecifier] | None = None,
        clbits: ClbitSpecifier | Sequence[ClbitSpecifier] | None = None,
        front: bool = False,
        inplace: bool = False,
        wrap: bool = False,
    ):

    num_self_ancillas = len(self.ancillas)
    num_other_ancillas = len(other.ancillas)
    if num_other_ancillas > 0:
        if num_self_ancillas < num_other_ancillas:
            extra_ancillas = []
            for _ in range(num_other_ancillas - num_self_ancillas):
                extra_ancillas.append(AncillaQubit())
            self.add_bits(extra_ancillas)
        qubits = qubits + self.ancillas[0:num_other_ancillas]
    
    return self.compose(other, qubits, clbits, front, inplace, wrap)

QuantumCircuit.compose_with_auto_ancillas = compose_with_auto_ancillas

Basically, compose_with_auto_ancillas() method checks if the subcircuit uses ancilla qubits more than what is already in the main circuit and add them before composing the subcircuit.
An example usage:
# A subcircuit:
qr1 = QuantumRegister(4)
anc1 = AncillaRegister(2)
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(qr1, anc1)

qc1.ccx(qr1[0], qr1[1], anc1[0])
qc1.ccx(qr1[2], anc1[0], anc1[1])
qc1.cx(anc1[1], qr1[3])
qc1.ccx(qr1[2], anc1[0], anc1[1])
qc1.ccx(qr1[0], qr1[1], anc1[0])

# The main circuit:
# Note that, you don't have to add any ancilla at the beginning,
# they will be added when needed.
circ = QuantumCircuit(4)
circ.h([0, 1, 2, 3])
circ.barrier()
circ.compose_with_auto_ancillas(qc1, [0, 1, 2, 3], inplace=True)


The way I would go about this is by

first creating an additional QuantumRegister for the ancilla qubits
then adding that QuantumRegister to the original QuantumCircuit with add_register
and finally concatenating your multiplication circuit to your original circuit with the compose API.


Thanks for the answer, so this is how I have been doing it till now, but this is getting more and more complicated as I compose logically smaller (but qubit-count wise larger) building blocks.
